# Software service to retain coursework

Tags: educational

I'm second year university student in the United States and I've realized that I have a hard time retaining a lot of the core concepts I've learned in previous semesters.

I'm looking for a software service where I can input the courses I've taken and then I'm quizzed weekly on different topics I've learned in past semesters.

For example, if I input a topic of "digital logic" as a course that I've taken, I might see a question like this:

> If A and B are binary numbers, then what is the inverse of `A and B` (denoted (A.B)')?
>
> 1. A'B'
> 2. A+B
> 3. B'A'
> 4. A'+B'

Thanks in advance for any information on the subject.

Comment: Nodcah - how would the past data be a quiz? Would there be some predefined QA? Can it be housed online or need to be local?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I'm looking to be quizzed on predefined questions about the coursework I've taken in past semesters. So **not** something like [Quizlet](http://quizlet.com) where I make my own questions then answer them, but something that has a list of the core concepts of the course. I've added an example to the question for clarity. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NimbleNotes](https://nimblenotes.com/). What you can do:

- you create your study notebooks, where you can input your files, texts like course summary, code, images, links, questions, definitions, LaTex math, etc.
- you can assign labels to the different elements to make searching for things simpler and easier,
- you are provided with some templates of how to organize your notes better,
- and you can generate study cards from the notes you have input via filters and labels to help you quiz yourself on what you've learned.

I would definitely advise having a look at it. I wish it came out earlier when I was still at school.

Comment: Thanks for the study tip, I'll check out NibleNotes! However, the program I'm looking for is more aimed at long-term retention of knowledge with question that I *don't* have to come up with.